# Metapost not centering label in circle

Tags: pdftex, metapost

I'm working on a document created in Plain TeX that contains many figures created with Metapost.  Many are letters centered in a circle.

With a recent upgrade to: MetaPost 2.00 (Web2C 2021) the text labels are no longer centered within the circle.

The complete code is:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
  draw fullcircle scaled 0.5cm;
  draw thelabel(btex A etex, (0,0));
endfig;

end;
```

which produces this [image: figure]

The log file is:

```
This is MetaPost, version 2.00 (Web2C 2021) (kpathsea version 6.3.3)  29 JUN 2022 08:51
**test.mp
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/metapost/base/mpost.mp
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.005) ) (./test.mp [1{psfonts.map}<cmr1
0.pfb>] )
1 output file written: test-1.eps
```

The mpx file is:

```
begingroup save _p,_r,_s,_n; picture _p; _p=nullpicture;
string _n[];
vardef _s(expr _t,_f,_m,_x,_y)(text _c)=
  addto _p also _t infont _f scaled _m shifted (_x,_y) _c; enddef;
_n0="cmr10";
_s("A",_n0,1.00000,0.0000,0.0000,);
setbounds _p to (0,0.0000)--(10.7929,0.0000)--
 (10.7929,6.8078)--(0,6.8078)--cycle;
_p endgroup
mpxbreak
```

I'm using Texlive 2021 on FreeBSD 13.1.

Comment: Seems to look fine using metapost 2.02 from TeXLive 2022.

Comment: Same here: no problem with MetaPost 2.02 from TexLive 2022 (code inserted in a LuaLaTeX program).

Comment: Can you post the complete program that produces the mis-aligned labels?  I mean with all the pre-amble etc.  And perhaps your log file?

Comment: My guess would be that something in your processing chain from MP to TeX to the visible output is messing things up.  Can you give us some more details about exactly how you produce the output?

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the post with the log file and further information.

Comment: Can you also show us your `.eps` output?  Not all of it, just the bit at the end after `EndProlog` -- probably the last 20 lines or so.

Comment: in my mpx I get `setbounds _p to (0,0.0000)--(7.4720,0.0000)--(7.4720,6.8078)--(0,6.8078)--cycle;` so apparently something is wrong with the font metrics??